# How to make a custom size array in a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, hashtable

I have code like so

```
#ifndef hashtable
#define hashtable

// define the maxmium size
#define INITIAL_SIZE 5
#define LOAD_FACTOR 0.7

typedef struct hashtable
{
    int keyArray[INITIAL_SIZE];

    // 1d array of strings with maximum length 100 (plus '\0 character')
    char valueArray[INITIAL_SIZE][100 + 1]; 
    bool isActiveArray[INITIAL_SIZE]; // for deleting elements

    int count;
    int capacity;
    double loadFactor;

    // true: linear probing, false: quadratic probing
    bool collisionHandler;

} table;

#endif
```

in `hashtable.h` file

in which I define a hashtable with a key array and value array and so on.
I am confused on how I could resize the hashtable, because whenever creating a new struct in order to resize, I fall into the problem that my `INITIAL_SIZE` cannot be changed, especially in a `#define` statement, although I want to make a new table that would have a capacity of `2*INITIAL_SIZE` and so on ...

Here is my code of initTable() where I make the table incase it is helpful

```
void initTable(table* p, int size, double loadFactor, bool collisionHandler) {
    // constructor
    p->count = 0;
    p->capacity = size;
    p->loadFactor = loadFactor; 
    p->collisionHandler = collisionHandler;

    memset( p->keyArray, 0, sizeof p->keyArray );
    memset( p->valueArray, 0, sizeof p->valueArray );
    memset( p->isActiveArray, 0, sizeof p->isActiveArray );    
    
}
```

How can I resize the array, open to any suggestions even if removing INITIAL_SIZE entirely

Thanks for the help,
pew

Comment: using ```INITIAL_SIZE``` as an array size means its constant, you want to resize your array so don't use constants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros (defines) are not variables, they are replaced by their values before the compilation, so in your code all the INITIAL_SIZE will be replaced by 5.

When you declare a variable in your code, it will be statically allocated on the stack and its size is constant. you cant change the size of an array in a structure so you need to have the arrays outside of the structure and pointers that points to it like that:

```c
typedef struct hashtable
{
    int    *keyArray;
    char   *valueArray; 
    bool   *isActiveArray;
    
    int    count;
    int    capacity;
    double loadFactor;
    
    bool   collisionHandler;
} table;
```

Then you will need to **dynamically allocate** the arrays with [malloc](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html). The malloc function take in argument the size that you want to allocate and return a pointer to the allocated area (on the heap).
for example:

```c
table p;
int   size = 5;
p.keyArray = malloc(size * sizeof(int)); // sizeof is a c operator that return the size of a type in bytes

if (p.keyArray == NULL)  // it is a good practice to protect a malloc by checking its return value
   exit(1);

//p.keyArray now points to an array of size 5, you can now use it like any other array
```

When you dont need the array anymore you must free the allocated memory with the free function

```c
free(p.keyArray);
```

finally here is the full code to perform the resizing of an array:

```c
void resize(int **array, int old_size, int new_size)
{
    int *new_array = malloc(new_size * sizeof(int)); // allocate the new area
    if (!new_array) // protect the malloc
       exit(1);
    memcpy(new_array, *array, old_size * sizeof(int)); // copy the content from the old area to the new one
    free(*array); // free the old area
    *array = new_array; // and change the pointer of the old area
}
```

or with realloc:

```c
void resize(int **array, int new_size)
{
    *array = realloc(*array, new_size * sizeof(int));
    if (!*array)
        exit(1);
}
```

edit:
as mentioned by Neil the realloc method is better because you let malloc do internal optimization (in case the area next to the initial area is sufficient it will just expand this area and this avoid to copy the content of the array). I just wanted to show you the malloc logic with the first version.

Comment: The `malloc` code _always_ copies the table, while the `realloc` code may expand the memory without copying; I think this is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jgiron42. However, there was one small flaw I ran into when testing your answer. The answer was successful for copying p->valueArray and p->isActiveArray; however, when copying p-keyArray of integers using memcpy, I found that the line needed to be `memcpy(new_keys, *keys, old_size*sizeof(int))`. Not sure if I did something wrong but that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

@jgiron42's answer is almost perfect using malloc to reallocate and using integer, char, and bool pointers for lists in hashtable.h, in my code/problem the only way to make it fully work was when copying a new key array of int* it needs to be done like so - > `memcpy(new_keys, *keys, old_size * sizeof(int));` instead of what works for char and bool arrays `memcpy(new_bools, *bools, old_size);`